# Fineuploader taking too long to upload files in IE9

Tags: fine-uploader

Hi I am using fineuploader 3.3.0 version.
 I am facing problem with `fineuploader in IE9`. as fine uploader does not support sizeLimit in ie9.
 I am checking the file size at server side with simple contentlength check  if `(this.Request.Files[0].ContentLength > 5242880)`.

but it took 1-2 mins to get this response. Also the `1.4 MB file` is taking too long to upload.

Can some one please let me know what is causing it, following is the fineuploader code I am using:-

```
 $('#restricted-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
        request: {
            endpoint: '/apm/api/job/UploadDocument/?category=' + JobDocuments.category + '&mode=' + JobDocuments.forceupload + '&jobid=' + job_manager_details.jobId
        },
        autoUpload: true,
        text: {
            uploadButton: 'Upload File'
        },
        multiple: false,
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'pdf'],
            sizeLimit: 5242880,
            itemLimit: 1
        },
        showMessage: function (message) {
            // Using Twitter Bootstrap's classes and jQuery selector and method
            $('#restricted-fine-uploader').append('<div class="alert alert-error">' + message + '</div>');
        }
    }).bind('submit', function (event, id, fileName) {
        $('#displaymessage').hide();
        $('li. qq-upload-fail').hide();
        job_manager_details.isuploading = 1;
        //            fileCount++;

    }).bind('complete', function (event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
        $('li. qq-upload-fail').hide();
        $('#displaymessage').hide();
        job_manager_details.isuploading = 0;
        if (responseJSON.success) {
            //                fileCount--;
            ShowJobDocuments();
            //                if (fileCount == 0 && !$('div.alert-error').html()) {
           $('#jobDocumentDialog').dialog("close");
            //                }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue and found one more clue.

The VM is incredibly slow (WinXP/IE8) while the network was a NAT'd but it became very fast as soon as it was switched to being bridged.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of the upload should not be influenced by Fine Uploader in any noticeable way.  All Fine Uploader does for non File API browsers, such as IE9 and older, is submit a `<form>` containing the file and related parameters.  If you are noticing slow upload times, most likely something in your environment is the cause of the issue.  You haven't provided any additional information about your environment, so I can't offer any advice on that front.

As you may already know, file size checking is not possible client-side in IE9 and earlier due to lack of File API support.

Comment: Can you please confirm what environmental factors can affect this, as an example(except slow internet)? also I have enabled debug mode and following is the log:-      LOG: [FineUploader] Processing 1 files or inputs... 
LOG: [FineUploader] Sending upload request for 0  ----- at this stage it stops, and keep processing.... :(

Comment: After the 2nd log message, "sending upload request", the request is out of the control of Fine Uploader as it has been sent.  More specifically, the hidden form has been submitted.  Is a VM involved in any way here?  I have seen weird network slowness from time to time when a VM is involved.